# While iterating an array of CBPeripherals with ForEach I get a CBPeer

Tags: swiftui, core-bluetooth

I just started learning Swift and SwiftUI and I came across a problem that I'm having some trouble to solve.

I'm trying to create a list of available Bluetooth peripherals with buttons to select which to connect to, but for some reason the ForEach statement is iterating CBPeer objects instead of CBPeripheral ones.

Am I doing something wrong or it's just not possible to iterate through an array of CBPeripheral objects?

My code:

```
struct BluetoothPeripheralSelection: View{
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral]
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Section(header: Text("Select bluetooth peripheral")){
                ForEach(peripherals, id: \.self){peripheral in
                    Button(action: {}){
                        Text(peripheral.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like compiler reports wrong error. The reason is that `peripheral.name` is optional, so use instead something like (tested with Xcode 12)

```
Button(action: {}){
    Text(peripheral.name ?? peripheral.identifier.uuidString)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, providing a default value solved the problem.
That error was making me doubt of what I thought I knew about Swift.